# Confusion of the “size n” used in the central limit theorem

Tags: statistics

First of all, let me re-state a version of the central limit theorem:-

If $X_1, X_2, …, X_n$ is a random sample of size $n$ from any infinite population with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then , with $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}(X_1+X_2+...+X_n)$, we have $E[\bar{X}] = \mu$ and $Var [\bar{X}] = \dfrac {\sigma^2}{n}$

In which, I found only one “***n***”.

Now, consider a numeric example trying to verify the fact.

Let {2, 3, 6, 8, 11} be a population with size $ = 5 = n_0$, say. [This “$n_0$” will not cause any trouble in the following discussion.]

From that we get $\mu = … = 6$ and $\sigma^2 = ... = \dfrac {54}{5}$.

Next, we take all possible samples of size $2 = n_1$, say, from the population.

These samples are (2,2), (2, 3), …, (11, 11) with a total of $25 = n_2$, say.

From these order pairs, we get a random variable of means with $25 = n_2$ in total.

The corresponding probabilities are in the form of $\dfrac {j}{25}$ where j could be 1, 2, 3, or 4

Using these data, we get the mean of the means $ = \mu_{\bar X } = … = \dfrac {150}{25} = 6 = \mu $. [So far so good.]

Also, $\sigma_{\bar X}^2 = \dfrac {(2 – 6)^2 + …}{25} = … = \dfrac {27}{5}$, which can be interpreted as $\dfrac {1}{2}(\dfrac {54}{5})$ in order to agree with the formula $\sigma_{\bar X}^2 = \dfrac {\sigma^2}{n}$, if $n$ is $2$.

My questions is:-
In the theorem, there is only one “n”, but in the example, we have two (namely $n_1$, $n_2$, and not counting the $n_0$). Which is which?

According to my understanding about the theorem, $n$ is $n_2 = 25$.

However, in the very last step, the “$n$” used in the formula $\sigma_{\bar X}^2 = \dfrac {\sigma^2}{n}$ is $n_1 = 2$.

Added: Although this is a finite example, one can imagine that the population is large and after taking samples from it, we still have to distinguish the $n, n_1,n_2$ problem.

Comment: You already make a mistake at line 5 when you introduce your example: the theorem talks about an infinite population, you introduce a finite one.

Comment: @Raskolnikov That is true. However, very often we have to use the same theorem to deal with populations of the finite size.

Comment: @Raskolnikov You could imagine we have an infinite population, with "equally many" of each of 2, 3, 6, 8 and 11. That would make the theorem apply to this case as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have in your example, named the size of the population, the number of samples taken and the total possible number of samples. Only one of these three appears in the theorem (and only one makes sense to do calculations with infinite populations). That's the number of samples taken, your $n_1$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more explaining why $n_1$ is that "n" in the theorem. Or equivalently, why $n_2$ is not the correct "n".

Comment: @Mick In your question post, the theorem says "a random sample of size $n$", and you talk about the "samples of size $2=n_1$". Comparing the two makes it pretty clear that they correspond.

Comment: Can I interpret in the following way?:- From (2, 2), I get the mean $= X_1 = 2$; from (2, 3), I get the mean $= X_2 = 2.5$; and so on. Then, I have “the mean of the means” $= \dfrac {1}{n}(X_1 + X_2 + … + X_n)$. It seems to me that this equality matches part of the statement of the central limit theorem. If this is so, then $n = 25 = n_2$.